# Normal ordering of number operators $n$th power

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wick-theorem

In resources I keep seeing the normally ordered form of the number operator to the $n$th power,
$${(a^\dagger a)}^n=\sum_{k=1}^n S(n,k){(a^\dagger)}^ka^k.$$
Why are we interested in the number operator to a power's values? Is it connected to vacuum expectations? Do the Stirling numbers apply to the normal ordering of problems that aren't of the form $(a^\dagger a)^n$?